# How to Create Virtual Bootable Thunderbolt Drive

Tags: macos, thunderbolt, bootable-disk

Considering the speed and versatility of Thunderbolt, it can be very useful to boot from a thunderbolt device on a Mac.

Would it be possible to use a disk image on one Mac to create a virtual bootable drive? On top of that, how can you connect one Mac over Thunderbolt to the other, and actually boot from the disk image stored on the other Mac?

Comment: Do you want to boot Mac(a) from a diskimage stored on Mac(b) or do you want to boot Mac(a) from a diskimage stored on Mac(a)

Comment: I’m hoping to find a way to boot Mac A from a disk image stored on Mac B, ideally without actually shutting down Mac B. I have found out I could maybe make Mac B a NetBoot server, but that requires Mac A to explicitly trust it before that will work.

Comment: What about creating another bootable partition on Mac(B)

Comment: The reason I ask about a virtual disk is because I’d like to avoid actually partitioning or even shutting down Mac B. I hope to figure out how to do this with preexisting tools, then compile a software product that would allow your Mac (B) to offer itself as a boot source over Thunderbolt to Mac A. This would ideally only happen while the product is running.

Comment: If you’re using APFS you can create partitions with a variable size, so it won’t fill up unecesary space

Comment: It's certainly very useful to have partitions with variable size, I just would like to be able to toggle the existence of this bootable partition/volume/disk image within macOS. Is is possible to create and remove partitions quickly in this way? Something that could be connected to an on-screen switch even?

Comment: Automator can be set up to create/delete partitions just with a press on a button, plus Automator is able to run shellscripts in the same workflow...

Comment: @harcker can you please explain how to use Automator to manage disk partitions? Also, can this partitioning be done without interfering with normal use of the Mac ex: System momentarily freezing while disk is being partitioned?

Comment: partitioning can be done with the partition disk command (it doesn't support   APFS) or with the do shell script command (requires a command, but it supports APFS)

Comment: @harker, I've been doing research and I don't think that I can image an APFS volume with a bootable dmg file, so I would have to partition the disk itself.